# Woocoomerce how to fetch only instock products

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, woocommerce

Good day experts,

Please I need your help, I created a method that fetches all Woocommerce products to my ionic app using Woocommerce API.

Please how do I fetch only products that are in-stock?

**woocommerce.service.ts**

```
  //get all Products
  getAllProducts(){
    this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}products?per_page=11&consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`
      console.log(this.apiUrl);
     this.products = this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe( retry(1),catchError(this.handleError) );
      return this.products;
  }
```

**products.html**

```
 <ion-row class="container">
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let product of products" > 
            <ion-card >
           <img src="{{ product.images[0].src }} "/>
              <ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-title>{{ product.name }}</ion-card-title>
              </ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-content>
                <ion-label>
                 <h3>Price: {{ product.price | number:'1.0-0' }}</h3>
                      
                </ion-label>
              </ion-card-content>
              <ion-button  size="small" expand="full" color="success"  >
                Order     
              </ion-button>
            </ion-card>  
      </ion-col>  
    </ion-row>
```

Comment: please post your JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `stock_status=instock` to the url to limit the search for only instocked products....

```
${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}products?per_page=11&consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&stock_status=instock&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}
```